# Order results by `OR` statements MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that uses the `OR` statement at the `WHERE` clause.

How can I order my elements by it's OR statement appearance?
For example, imagine the following query:

```
SELECT id,message,link,data_hora,like_count FROM mensagens 
WHERE message = 'pineapple juice' OR message = 'pineapple' OR messsage = 'juice'
```

I would like that the results first showed the "pinapple juice" results and after that, the others, I couldn't think of solving this with the `ORDER BY` statement

Comment: Just a suggestion: SELECT id,message,link,data_hora,like_count FROM mensagens WHERE message IN ('pineapple juice' , 'pineapple', 'juice') ORDER BY message DESC

Comment: @AndaIancu That only works because juice is alphabetically before pineapple. If it was "pineapple quarters", you'd have "quarters" appearing first in the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `FIELD()`. The simpliest answer in `MySQL`.

```
SELECT
FROM 
WHERE
ORDER BY FIELD(message, 'pineapple juice', 'pineapple', 'juice')
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Wish SQL Server had this!

Comment: @Andomar sad since only mysql has this. Hope sql server soon supports this. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression

```
SELECT id,message,link,data_hora,like_count 
FROM mensagens 
WHERE message = 'pineapple juice' OR message = 'pineapple' OR messsage = 'juice'
ORDER BY CASE message WHEN 'pineapple juice' THEN 0
                      WHEN 'pineapple' THEN 1
                      WHEN 'juice' THEN 2 
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
order by  message = 'pineapple juice' desc, message = 'pineapple' desc, messsage = 'juice' desc
```

In MySQL, a comparison returns a boolean value which is interpreted as a 0 (false) or 1 (true).  The `desc` puts the true value first.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by case when message = 'pineapple juice' then 1
              when message = 'pineapple' then 2
              when message = 'juice' then 3
         end
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

ORDER BY  message = 'pineapple juice' DESC, message  = 'pineapple' DESC,  messsage = 'juice' DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
order by
        case message -- First, the where clause order
        when 'pineapple juice' then 1
        when 'pineapple' then 2
        when 'juice' then 3
        else 4 end
,       message -- Second, order by message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CASE message WHEN 'pineapple juice' THEN 2 WHEN 'pineapple' THEN 1 WHEN 'juice' THEN 0 END DESC
```

Or something similar.